# Sublime Text 2 doesn't support Chinese words on Linux (Ubuntu), anybody know how to solve this?

Tags: characters, chinese

Sublime Text 2 goes wrong with Chinese words on Linux, neither can type in any Chinese words, nor display it correctly. But it seems that the official site said it has support UTF-8 characters. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**display error solved as following, but type error not.**
First, you need install simsun font.
Second, edit 'preferences --> file Settings -- user' as following:

```
{
    "font_face": "simsun",
    "font_size": 10.0
}
```

*simsun font downloading link: http://depositfiles.com/files/hn9dfwdap*

*reference: http://blog.mckelv.in/?p=800*

Answer (score 0):

如果你的ubuntu已经有中文字体的话，你甚至不用再安装任何字体。
edit 'preferences --> file Settings -- user' as following:

```
{
    "font_face": "WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono",
    "font_size": 13.0
}
```

不过这只能解决显示问题，不能解决中文输入的问题。

Comment: Could you possibly translate this to english?